# Send POST request with cookie and get content

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api, httpwebresponse

I'm building tests to my Web API MVC application and I'm trying to send a POST request. I need to send a cookie, and then read the content I get back from the response.

I tried to use `HttpWebRequest` and it worked great with the cookie (I get StatusCode OK) but I can't read the content from the response:

```
public static HttpWebResponse WebRequest(string methodURL, string method, string json, HttpCookie cookie)
        {
            string URL = baseURL + methodURL;
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = method;
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie.Name+"="+cookie.Value);
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            try
            {
                return (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
                {
                    return (HttpWebResponse)response;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I tried to use `HttpResponseMessage` to get the content back but I couldn't send the cookie right - I get StatusCode "Unauthorized".

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage WebRequest(string methodURL, string method, string json, HttpCookie cookie)
        {
            string URL = baseURL + methodURL;

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                  .Accept
                  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value);

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL);
            request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value);
            request.Properties.Add("Cookie", cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value);
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> r  = client.SendAsync(request)
              .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
              {
                  HttpResponseMessage message = responseTask.Result;
                  message.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value);
                  return message;

              });
            return r.Result;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the first way, you have to use a `cookieContainer`

```
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
```

to read the response you can use something like this,

```
var responseStr = new StringBuilder();
try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    var responseCode = response.StatusCode;

    var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    if (receiveStream != null)
    {
        var instr = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = instr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            responseStr.Append(inputLine);
        }
        instr.Close();
    }
} catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: I don't have "client.CookieContaine"

Comment: In your case would be httpWebRequest.CookieContainer